# Spreadsheetgear run macro?

Tags: .net, spreadsheetgear

Is it possible to run existing excel macros in Spreadsheetgear?

Comment: I've been searching for the web for this feature but no luck so far. I'm about to give up. I think this question will never be answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SpreadsheetGear can open xls and xlsm workbooks with VBA macros, preserve the macros, and save the macros back to disk, but SpreadsheetGear cannot execute VBA code.

SpreadsheetGear does provide an API which is similar to Excel, so you can frequently move your VBA code to VB.NET or C#.

SpreadsheetGear also supports custom functions, but again, you must provide .NET implementations of them or they will return #NAME!

Comment: Hi Joe. I'm glad I found this answer, but it is almost five years old now. Is this still the case? I'm expecting nothing has changed based on the product history I found [here](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/downloads/whatsnew.aspx), but I thought I'd check. [Roadmap?](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/products/roadmap.aspx) ;) Thank you!

Comment: @Joe Erickson. As today are macros supported on SpreadsheetGear 2017?